# Forcing /login/callback passport nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, passport.js

I have my passport nodejs set up properly, it is now authenticating using azure ad. the weird thing is, when I try to click on any other links on the page, or try to actually specify the route I want to go to in the url, it always adds /login in-front. (ex. http://localhost:3000/login/catalogue) I couldn't find any help online, and have been at it for far to many hours...

Here's my code. Thanks in advance!

```
   var SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;

passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
  {
    path: '/login/callback',

    entryPoint: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/...',
    issuer: '...'
  },
  
  function(profile, done) {
    findByEmail(profile.email, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      return done(null, user);
      
    });
  })
);

app.post('/login/callback',
function(req, res) {
  console.log('inside /login/callback')
  //after login, goes here, but renders back to login/callback. then back here.
 res.render('index.ejs')
}
);

app.get('/login',
  passport.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true }),
  function(req, res) {
      console.log("inside azuread /login get passport saml")
     res.render('index.ejs')
  }



 );
```

Comment: What document are you referring to?

Comment: I’m referring to this one here (the NODEjs section midway down) https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2016/12/29/azure-ad-saml-federation-application-tutorial/